# TextButton and ElevatedButton update

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am trying to update FlatButton to TextButton and RaisedButton to ElevatedButton while keeping the  style, size, position, and color. How do I do that? I need to update in order for the Logout button and Account Settings button to work. When I keep the deprecated feature, the Logout button is not visible and the Account Settings gives the error **"Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null"** right after clicking the gears icon.

```
Container(
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: ()=> print("clicked"),
                  child: Text(
                    "Update", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  highlightColor: Colors.grey,
                  splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 10.0, 30.0, 10.0),
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, bottom: 1.0),
              ),


Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 50.0),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  onPressed: logoutUser,
                  child: Text(
                    "Logout",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Complete code below

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:telegramchatapp/Widgets/ProgressWidget.dart';
import 'package:telegramchatapp/main.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';


class Settings1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        title: Text(
          "Account Settings",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SettingsScreen(),
    );
  }
}


class SettingsScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  @override
  State createState() => SettingsScreenState();
}



class SettingsScreenState extends State<SettingsScreen>
{
  TextEditingController nickNameTextEditingController;
  TextEditingController aboutMeTextEditingController;
  SharedPreferences preferences;
  String id = "";
  String nickname = "";
  String aboutMe = "";
  String photoUrl = "";
  File imageFileAvatar;
  bool isLoading;
  final FocusNode nickNameFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode aboutMeFocusNode = FocusNode();

  get picker => null;


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    readDataFromLocal();
  }

  void readDataFromLocal() async
  {
    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    id = preferences.getString("id");
    nickname = preferences.getString("nickname");
    aboutMe = preferences.getString("aboutMe");
    photoUrl = preferences.getString("photoUrl");

    nickNameTextEditingController = TextEditingController(text: nickname);
    aboutMeTextEditingController = TextEditingController(text: aboutMe);

    setState(() {

    });
  }
  
  
  Future getImage() async
  {
    File newImageFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    
    if(newImageFile != null)
    {
      setState(() {
        this.imageFileAvatar = newImageFile;
        isLoading = true;
      });
    }
    
    //uploadImageToFireStoreAndStorage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              //Profile image - Avatar
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      (imageFileAvatar == null)
                          ? (photoUrl != "")
                          ? Material(
                              //display already existing - old image file
                              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    strokeWidth: 2.0,
                                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                                  ),
                                  width: 200.0,
                                  height: 200.0,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                ),
                                imageUrl: photoUrl,
                                width: 200.0,
                                height: 200.0,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(125.0)),
                              clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                            )
                          : Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 90.0, color: Colors.grey,)
                          : Material(
                              //display the new updated image here
                                child: Image.file(
                                  imageFileAvatar,
                                  width: 200.0,
                                  height: 200.0,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(125.0)),
                                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                            ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.camera_alt, size: 100.0, color: Colors.white54.withOpacity(0.3),
                        ),
                        onPressed: getImage,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                        highlightColor: Colors.grey,
                        iconSize: 200.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                width: double.infinity,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              ),

              //Input Fields
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0), child: isLoading ? circularProgress() : Container(),),

                  //username
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      "Profile Name : ",
                      style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, bottom: 5.0, top: 10.0),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Theme(
                      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "e.g. SR12",
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                        controller: nickNameTextEditingController,
                        onChanged: (value){
                          nickname = value;
                        },
                        focusNode: nickNameFocusNode,
                      ),
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                  ),

                  //aboutMe - user Bio
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      "About Me : ",
                      style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, bottom: 5.0, top: 10.0),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Theme(
                      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Bio...",
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                        controller: aboutMeTextEditingController,
                        onChanged: (value){
                          aboutMe = value;
                        },
                        focusNode: aboutMeFocusNode,
                      ),
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                  ),
                ],
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              ),

              //Buttons
              Container(
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: ()=> print("clicked"),
                  child: Text(
                    "Update", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  highlightColor: Colors.grey,
                  splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 10.0, 30.0, 10.0),
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, bottom: 1.0),
              ),

              //Logout Button
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 50.0),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  onPressed: logoutUser,
                  child: Text(
                    "Logout",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }


  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<Null> logoutUser() async
  {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
    await googleSignIn.signOut();

    this.setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });

    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Raised button wont work because you have assigned Future<Null> to it try using () { await logoutUser(); } in its onpressed.

Comment: I'm trying to make RaisedButton work. Im using an old Flutter 2.0  code and updating to the current Flutter update.